# Pulling cell data from Google Sheets to a text box or label in Google App Maker

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-maker

I am working on an app in Google app maker, and I want to pull specific cell values from sheets into the app.

I've tried using API's like Sheetsu,only to find that the only way the data will be input is using iFrame as a chart. The code below works when input into a test window of Tryit Editor v3.6, but will not correctly pull the values when input into an HTML widget in App Maker

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Pending Matters</th>
    <th>Closed Matters</th>
    <th>Risk Meter</th>
    <th>Closing %</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody sheetsu="https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/386ed1faa5dc" sheetsu-limit="3">
    <tr>
      <td>{{Pending Matters}}</td>
      <td>{{Closed Matters}}</td>
      <td>{{Risk Meter}}</td>
      <td>{{Closing %}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//load.sheetsu.com"></script>
```

Comment: Did you put the script source in App Maker external libraries under settings?

Comment: Added //load.sheetsu.com into the external libraries, is there something else that should be added? I was not sure that was the right thing to add to begin with

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used apis or sheetsu before, but the GAS basic calls to sheets/gmail/etc work the same way they do in regular GAS.

The way i'd solve your problem is to

- Appmaker: Create a data source with the same fields as your sheet

  Appmaker Server Script: open the sheet, read the values, and write
  them to the datasource (using SpreadsheetApp).

  AppmakerPage: Display the datasource with a table widget

  AppmakerPage: call the server script on page or app load.